# RoR: How to prevent Url change after erronous edit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a standard generated scaffold project, when you are on an edit page, the URL looks like;

> /something/3/edit

However, when the page doesn't validate, it runs the following code:

> ```
>    format.html { :action => "edit" }
> ```

and the page url changes to;

> /something/3

(no /edit)

Why is this is this and how to prevent it, as it looks inconsistent to me and thus confusing.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the rendering not change the URL.

When you made an update you made :

```
PUT /something/3
```

So if it's failed, there are no URL changing. just rendering of your action file ( not action code ).

So if you want have `/new` of `/edit` you need made a :

```
redirect_to :edit
```

In this case, you lost all information like `object.errors`.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but isn't that rather clunky? /edit should be the edit url, not suddenly without edit. I haven't seen this behavior with other frameworks yet, it seems fundamentally wrong to me. But thank you for your help.

Comment: this behaviour is REST compliant.

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure when fails the code is  `format.html { :action => "new" }`?

It should be

```
format.html { :action => "edit" }
```

I checked it in my own scaffolded code and I get "edit" instead of "new" on that line.

Hope this helps.